# Can't get a live image from a Pi Cam in Python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, ocr

I have a Sudoku Solver on my Raspberry Pi using Python and OpenCV. Currently, it is using a Kinect sensor for the Xbox 360, but now I want it to work using a Raspberry Pi Camera. I have tried using
`for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True)`
but this doesn't work with my current code, I think it's because of the frame rate. The code I am using is a tutorial and all of the code can be found [here](http://www.mikedeff.in/sudokuSolver.py). It is essential that I use the Pi Camera. Please help.

Comment: I presume you have enabled the camera in `raspi-config`? Can you capture still images with it? Does the camera light up?

Comment: @MarkSetchell The camera works fine, it's just I'm not sure if there's a way to get a live image from the camera

Comment: Set `stream = camera.VideoCapture(0`), and `status,frame = stream.read()` returns status, frame. You can use `while` loop while status is true and read the frame againg with `_,frame = camera.read()`